# Using javac with import

Tags: java, javac

I try to compile this code:

```
package edu;
import java.io.*;
public class Main { ... }
```

with `javac` called from command line. I know that I need to do it this way:

```
javac -classpath /lib/* Main.java
```

and put .jar file with the 'java.io.*' classes in 'lib' folder in my project's directory.

Is my javac command correct - especially path to '/lib/*'?

How do I find the desired .jar file(s) so that I can copy them to my project's lib directory?

Comment: Have you set the path in environment variables correctly for javac directory ? If So, Try javac Main.java , this should work.

Comment: @sarvajeetsuman thanks, I was confused by similar project with non-core imports which didn't work. This one actually produces an error for other reason. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package java.io is part of core java, you do not have to put anything extra into your classpath